# how to convert 01 April to 31 March in linux shell

Tags: linux, date

I want to convert 01 April to 31 March how to do it using linux

shell script

```
$ date -d "01-apr-2009 30 days" +%d-%b-%Y
01-May-2009
$ date -d "01-apr-2009 12 month" +%d-%m-%Y
01-04-2010
```

start_date=01-Apr  i need to calculate end_date ie .. end_date=31-March

Comment: it is unclear what you mean here. Please [edit] to make it more clear! Check [ask] as well, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to add "ago" if you'd like to calculate past date from the provided date.

Example:

```
$ date -d "2016-08-10 10:30:00 1 day ago"
Tue Aug  9 10:30:00 CEST 2016
$ date -d "2016-08-10 10:30:00 2 months ago"
Fri Jun 10 10:30:00 CEST 2016
$ date -d "2016-08-10 10:30:00 3 hours ago"
Wed Aug 10 07:30:00 CEST 2016
```